# What is the quickest way to validate a postal code as existing on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, validation, postal-code

I have an iPhone application which accepts valid zip codes as input. The input can be quickly validated for format; I am looking for methods to validate whether it exists or not.

What is the most efficient way to test whether a given Canadian or US postal code exists, without storing a database of valid codes on the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex, but that will only tell you if the code is in the valid *format*, but doesn't tell you if the zip code actually exists.  For example, "99999" is a valid US zip code format (5 digits), but is not a valid zip code.

I'd find some online service that allows you submit a zip code and returns you the cities that correspond to it.  Some online weather services (Yahoo, Weather.com) have a developer API that is pretty easy to integrate.

Comment: +1 for calling out to a web service. I've done this with similar requirements, except I used the National Weather Service's database.

Comment: I can validate the format already. I'm looking for methods to check whether the (valid) postal code exists

Comment: also note that a (valid US) zip code can have a dash (-) and 4 additional digits, after the first 5 digits

Answer (score 1):

Have a look <strike>[here](http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256F6B005294C2)</strike> for a regex that validates the postal code.

**Edit:** [Here](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=23)'s the proper regexp that validates three types of Postal Codes, 5 digit US ZIP code, 5 digit US ZIP code + 4, and 6 digit alphanumeric Canadian Postal Code. The first link that I included originally is incorrect as it does not validate the canadian postal code...ooops. Thanks to ***David Kanerek*** for the point out.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: He specifically included Canadian postal codes which use letters.